# How to play sound when phone screen is off with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _player = AudioPlayer();
    _player.setAsset('assets/audio/sample.mp3');

    _controller.addStatusListener((status) {
      if(status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        _player.play();
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm new to Flutter and I'm working on getting it to play an mp3 notification sound at the end of an animation timer I have made.

I'm only working on the Android app for the moment. The above code shows that I am setting a status listener in the initState for the animation completed state. It works fine when the screen is on, but if the screen is off, the sound isn't played till the screen is unlocked again.

I'm using [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) pub dev package to get the audio working, and have been looking at [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) pub dev package as a way to try to get it to work. I'm finding integrating audio_service a little confusing, as it looks as though it is meant for something a little bigger than what I need. Is there a simple approach to what I want in all this?

Answer (score 1):

If you need better queue management I am still going to strongly recommend you audio_service, in any case [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) recently added [flauto](https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_sound/pull/243) with background support and very easy integration.